# When I use Pyinstaller, Pycharm ignores the "Pyinstaller" module installed, and uses instead the one installed in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have a 2 almost identical projects on pycharm. I created each with it's own "venv", both venv have "Pyinstaller" module installed.

When I use "Pynstaller" command inside Pycharm venv terminal, in the first proyect, it uses the "Pyinstaller" module that is installed in it's venv.

In the second proyect, the same command ignores it's installed module, and uses "Pyinstaller" that is inside *C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller*

What's the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted any files created by Pycharm, trashed the venv, and made a new one, installed the same modules and it worked.

Comment: Please select this answer as correct with the tick underneath the voting buttons.